# How to create single row panda DataFrame with headers from big panda DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame which contains 55000 rows  and 3 columns
I want  to  return every row as DataFrame from this bigdataframe  for using it  as  parameter of different function.
My idea was iterating over big DataFrame by iterrows(),iloc  but I can't make it as DataFrame it is showing series type. How could I solve this

Answer (score 0):

I think it is obviously not necessary, because index of Series is same like columns of DataFrame.

But it is possible by:

```
df1 = s.to_frame().T
```

Or:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([s.to_numpy()], columns=s.index)
```

Also you can try yo avoid [`iterrows`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316), because obviously very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're doing something not optimal if you need what you describe. That said, if you need each row as a dataframe:

```
l = [pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(df))]
```

This makes a list of dataframes for each row in `df`